# An example of a random variable $y\in L^\dagger_2$ having more than one linear combination, $y = \Sigma_{i}\alpha_i x_i = \Sigma_{i}\beta_i x_i$

Tags: random-variable, stochastic-processes, sum, linearity

In the answer for the following exercise:

> Let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a finite collection of random variables with $E(x_i^2) \lt \infty$ ($i = 1,..., n$). Show that the set of all linear combinations $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i x_i$ constitutes a vector space, which we denote by $L^\dagger_2$,

there's a statement that I don't really understand, that is:

> The difficulty is that a random variable $y = \Sigma_{i}\alpha_i x_i$ might also be expressible as $y = \Sigma_{i}\beta_i x_i$, where $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \ne (\beta_1,...,\beta_n)$.

For simplicity, suppose that $n=2$ so we have only two random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the collection. How could I construct an example where $y=\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2=\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$ where $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)\ne (\beta_1, \beta_2)$?

Comment: for your n=2 example, you would be able to do this exactly when $x_1 = a x_2$ for some constant $a$ (such as 1). In generally, you will be able to multiply express a linear combination in terms of its coefficients when the vectors constituting it are linearly dependent.

Comment: As emphasized by the context of the exercise, it isn't about random variables: it's purely about linear algebra.  Let $x_2=-x_1,$ for instance.  Then $\sum \alpha_i x_i = \alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2=(\alpha_1-\alpha_2+\gamma)x_1+\gamma x_2$ for any real number $\gamma.$

Comment: BTW, it's hard to see how that statement is any difficulty at all.  All you need to do in this exercise is apply the closure property, which is that any linear combination of linear combinations of the $x_i$ is a linear combination of them.

Comment: @JohnMadden and whuber Thanks for your comments! It's simpler than I thought it was.

Comment: @JohnMadden on second thought, I'm wondering if there's any other example where one is not a scalar multiple of the other, i.e. $x_1 \ne a x_2$?

Comment: @whuber I'll be remiss if I didn't mention why the author says it's hard. If more than one representation for a single random variable exists (as in the case we see here), there're at least two vectors **0**: one is $0 x_1+...+0 x_n$ the other is $(\alpha_1-\beta_1)x_1+...(\alpha_n-\beta_n)x_n$, so the make sure **0** is unique, we need the induced equivalence classes of coefficients.

Comment: That's a different issue: whether something is a vector space is the question; your last comment addresses whether a set of of vectors in that space are linearly independent.

Comment: @TranKhanh in the N=2 case, one being a multiple is the only circumstance where non-uniqueness of coefficients would occur. In the N=3 case and higher though, things are more subtle, as we can choose something like $x_3 = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ which would lead to the same issue. The question you reference is about starting to think about abstract vector spaces, but your confusion seems to be about the uniqueness of coefficients, and it might be worth going back to a "non-abstract" linear algebra textbook to review that topic.

Comment: @whuber It's true, the two issues are not the same. I just wanted to add some context not directly related to my question.

Comment: @JohnMadden, I can understand the proof under the linear algebra viewpoint, what still bothers me however is having some concrete, non-trivial (like $x_1=a x_2$) example for the case where a random variable could be represented by two or more sets of coefficients.

Comment: @TranKhanh as I mentioned, there is no such case for N=2. Can you let me know what you don't like about my N=3 case? (note that in my example we have $0=x_3-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$).

Comment: @JohnMadden I'm okay with your case, so there's no problem. Im my previous coment I wanted to mean $x_1=a x_2+b x_3$ for $N=3$, not the mistyped $x_1=a x_2$. Also, my calculation tells me that, with the definition of  "almost surely equal", there's only one case for the multiple representations of a random variable exists, that is when one variable is the linear combination of the rest for all finite values of $N$.

Comment: @TranKhanh regarding "there's only one case for the multiple representations of a random variable exists, that is when one variable is the linear combination of the rest for all finite values of ", that's exactly correct. But do notice that it's not always defined obviously as $x_i = x_j + x_k$; sometimes, the linear dependence is implicitly defined based on several equations and not obvious from just staring at them.